# Best Practice for Developing Core Functions in Symfony2?

Tags: function, bundle, symfony

I am an experienced Symfony user and have started using Symfony2 and absolutely love it. A big thank you to Fabien and the guys over at Sensio.

I am pretty much there now in terms of developing in Symfony2 thanks to the documentation available, but there is one area in particular that I am still not 100% sure on.

I have a number of core functions that I want to use in different areas of the application and just want to know what the best practice for this is?

I am currently creating a bundle that has a number of functions in that handles the processing of images.

Is this the best way to do this and if so how do I then use or include these functions across other bundles?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could just import the classes you want to use from your image handler bundle, but the way I would go about it is to register one or more [services](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/service_container.html#what-is-a-service) (like an image manager or thumbnail generator or whatnot) from your bundle so that the functionality you are creating will be available through the DIC for the entire application to use.

Comment: Hi Problematic, thanks for your quick response and your help. I am still slightly confused though. Is a service ultimately a bundle? I have read the service page in the Symfony2 documentation, but I cannot see where you would create the actual object file or what class file you would write the functions in? Any further help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Services are accessed using $x = $this->get("image_processor") instead of $x = new ImageProcessor(), where the image_processor service would be defined in your config/services.yml file. http://pastebin.com/67xmZKS8 is an example of a services file, for which you can leave out the tags and arguments field for the most general example. Services allow you to get a new object without having to remember what the constructor arguments are. Services are not bundles, but instead named object constructors predefined by you (or predefined by Symfony2 or by other bundles).

Comment: Hi Adrian, thanks for your comment and the link. I think I have got it now. I have basically created a new folder for my services under src/Acme/TestBundle/Services and added my services there. I have then used an extension through the DIC to load a services.yml file that loads all my services. I have done this after following [link](http://www.martinsikora.com/symfony2-and-dependency-injection). My only question now is how do I then use other services like the doctrine orm in my service?

Comment: Pass them as arguments in the service declaration, like @Adrian's link above: `@doctrine.orm.entity_manager` under `arguments` will pass the entity manager as a constructor argument (the `@` symbol indicates a reference to a service, rather than just a string).